# Use VSTS Rest API to set git repo permissions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way using the VSTS rest API to set permissions on a git repo?

I've got a script that creates a repo, and I want to extend that to set some default permissions (give the project collection build service contribute permissions).

I've read [the gui docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions) and looked through the [Rest API docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) but can't see that I can set permissions on a repo through the API. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, REST API can not set version control permissions (including git repo).

I posted an user voice [Set version control permissions by REST API](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32345533-set-version-control-permissions-by-rest-api) for this feature, you can vote and follow up.