# Need Rest API to get the permission details from Azure Devops using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I am looking for a Rest API url that will get me the detailed list of access for each user/group in each repositories from Azure Devops.

I have API URL that will return the repositories for each Project in Azure Devops, but my story is about validating the access for each user/group for each repositories on periodic basis with the help of Rest API.

Need Rest API which will return the access permission for each User/Group under the reposities from Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

> Need Rest API to get the permission details from Azure Devops using PowerShell

For now, I am afraid there is no such Rest API to get git repo permissions for each User/Group.

You can check the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411681/use-vsts-rest-api-to-set-git-repo-permissions) for some details.

Note: The use voice site is not currently active. You could submit a new one to our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

[image]

As test, I track it by press `F12` in Chrome browser then select `Network`:

e.g. I could use below REST API to get group `project collection build service accounts`  permission details for my team `MyTestProject` in below sample:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/f0a50df8-5a11-41c3-8d7e-22180f923c80/_api/_security/DisplayPermissions?__v=5&tfid=cb4ef03a-148d-49fc-9775-342fc3923737&permissionSetId=a39371cf-0841-4c16-bbd3-276e341bc052&permissionSetToken=%24%2FMyTestProject
```

[image]

But I could not debug this API to list the access permission for **each User/Group** under the reposities from Azure DevOps.

Hope this helps.